# WordPress Ajax Spitting out a page as a response?

Tags: theme-development, ajax

So I have attempted to create a class to contain the ajax based functions and what not, in PHP and then call that through the functions.php and then use javascript to make calls back. But I am so confused right now as to why things are not working. What happens is I get:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure if the above means that it failed to reach the class or what ...

The code:

```
<?php
namespace Freya\Ajax;

/**
 * This is an implementation of the IAjax Interface
 *
 * This class is one idea of how to implement the IAjax interface that
 * essentially governs how to do ajax with in WordPree Themes via the use of Freya.
 *
 * @see Freya\Ajax\IAjax
 */
class Ajax implements IAjax {

    /**
     * The registered name space for Freya.
     *
     * States where the namespace lives.
     *
     * @var string registeredNameSpace
     */
    private $registeredNameSpace = '';

    /**
     * Instance of \Freya\Templates\Builder
     *
     * @var \Freya\Templates\Builder $builder
     */
    private $builder;

    /**
     * Register the ajax call as add_action
     *
     * Register the <code>wp_ajax_</code> and <code>wp_ajax_nopriv_</code>.
     *
     * @param \Freya\Templates\Builder $builder
     */
    public function __construct(\Freya\Templates\Builder $builder) {
        $this->builder = $builder;

        add_action('wp_ajax_registerAjaxCall', array($this, 'registerAjaxCall'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_registerAjaxCall', array($this, 'registerAjaxCall'));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function registerAjaxCall() {
        $request = $_REQUEST['request_data'];

        if (isset($request['action'])) {
            $controllerAndAction = explode(':', $request['action']);

            $controller = $controllerAndAction[0]; // Controller
            $action = $controllerAndAction[1]; // Action
            $params = null; // Action params, assuming there are any.

            if (isset($request['params'])) {
                $params = $request['params'];
            }

            echo $this->callAction($controller, $action, $params);

        } else if (isset($request['type'])) {
            if (!isset($request['name'])) {
                require_once __DIR__ . '/Exception/AjaxException.php';
                throw new Exception\AjaxException(
                    'You must pass the name of the view, partial or form'
                );
            }

            $params = array(); // Form or view params, for views and partials these are turned into $param.

            if (isset($request['params'])) {
                $params = $request['params'];
            }

            echo $this->renderView($request['type'], $request['name'], $params);
        }

        die();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param String $namespace - The namespace the controllers live in.
     */
    public function registerControllerNamespace($namespace) {
        if (is_string($namespace)) {
            $this->registeredNameSpace = $namespace;
        } else {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/Exception/AjaxException.php';
            throw new Exception\AjaxException(
                'namespace must be a string.'
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the controller name space that you registered.
     *
     * @return String Namespace
     */
    public function getRegisteredControllerNameSpace() {
        return $this->registeredNameSpace;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param string $controller - The controller to call.
     * @param string $requestAction - The controller method to call.
     * @param mixed $requestActionParams - (Can be null) the params to pass to the controller action
     * @return mixed/json
     */
    public function callAction($controller, $requestAction, $requestActionParams = array()) {
        $namespace = rtrim($this->getRegisteredControllerNameSpace(), '\\') . '\\';

        if (!class_exists($namespace . $controller)) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/Exception/AjaxException.php';
            throw new Exception\AjaxException(
                'No controller called: ' .$controller. ' exists under the name space registered.'
            );
        }

        $classReflectionObject = new \ReflectionClass($namespace . $controller);

        if (!$classReflectionObject->hasMethod($requestAction)) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/Exception/AjaxException.php';
            throw new Exception\AjaxException(
                'Controller does not have the following method: ' . $requestAction
            );
        }

        $classInstance = $classReflectionObject->newInstanceArgs(array());
        return call_user_func(array($classInstance, $requestAction), $requestActionParams);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param string $type - view, form or partial
     * @param string $template
     * @param mixed $params - params for the view, form or partial
     * @return string html
     */
    public function renderView($type, $template, array $params = array()) {
        $viewHtml = '';

        if ($type === 'view') {
            ob_start();
            $this->builder->renderView($template, $params);
            return $viewHtml = ob_get_clean();
        } else if ($type === 'partial') {
            ob_start();
            $this->builder->renderPartial($template, $params);
            return $viewHtml = ob_get_clean();
        } else if ($type === 'form') {
            return $this->builder->renderForm('\\' . $template, $params);
        }
    }
}
```

This class then gets called by doing:

```
if (function_exists('childTemplateBuilder()')) {
    $ajax = new Freya\Ajax\Ajax(childTemplateBuilder());
} else {
    $ajax = new Freya\Ajax\Ajax(templateBuilder());
}

// Now we set up the controller namespace.
$ajax->registerControllerNamespace('FreyaTheme\\Controllers\\');
```

I have the javascript registered by doing:

```
add_action( 'init', 'enqueueFreyaAjax' );

function enqueueFreyaAjax() {
   wp_register_script( "script", APP_ASSETS.'js/script.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'script', 'FreyaAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );
}
```

And finally the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataObjectControllerActionCall = {
    'action': 'SampleController:action',
    'params': ['hello', 'world']
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: FreyaAjax.wp_url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {action: 'registerAjaxCall', data: dataObjectControllerActionCall},
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  })
});
```

So my question is, is the `registerAjaxCall` function not set up properly? I mean it gets a status 200 on a GET request but the response and the preview are showing a wordpress page....

Why?

All I want to do at this point is validate with an `echo` or a `var_dump` that it is reaching this `registerAjaxCall` function, so far - It doesn't seem to be making it in ...

Comment: Try this with `wp_die()` instead of `die()` - your WP Ajax endpoints should always end with `wp_die()`.

Comment: That didnt do anything, I threw the `wp_die()` at the top of the `registerAjaxCall` function and nothing happened. I still got the same output. How do I verify that WP Ajax Sees this end point? Like how do I verify it's existence? @MattvanAndel

Comment: As far as I can tell your hook is set up correctly. Is your ajax URL correct? You call `FreyaAjax.wp_url` in your ajax call, but define `FreyaAjax.ajaxurl` in `wp_localize_script()`.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot you see that request is sent to home page, not to `admin-ajax.php`. I guess reason is the one pointed out by @MattvanAndel: you're using, in the AJAX call in your js `url: FreyaAjax.wp_url,` but `FreyaAjax.wp_url` is **not** defined, what you have instead is `FreyaAjax.ajaxurl` that is set via `wp_localize_script('script', 'FreyaAjax', array('ajaxurl' => ...`